# http post request flutter

Tags: flutter, post

I am trying to make http post request with Id as my parameter. So when I type my Id and then I click submit, it will do http post request, but here I don't able to make Id as my params so I get error right now. Here is my code

```
Future<http.Response> postId(String id) async {
bool trustSelfSigned = true;
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient()
          ..badCertificateCallback =
              ((X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) =>
                  trustSelfSigned);
        IOClient http = new IOClient(httpClient);

        final response =
            await http.post('my api',
                headers: {
                  HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json',
                },
                body: json.encode({
                  "id": id,

                }));
        Map<String, dynamic> responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
        print(responseJson["data"]);
return response;
}
```

here is my textField

```
TextField(
                        controller: _nip,
                        decoration: new InputDecoration(
                          hintText: 'your id',
                        ),
                      ),
```

and here is my button

```
RaisedButton.icon(
                        onPressed: postId(id.text),
                        label: Text(
                          'Submit',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                      )
```

Comment: Show where you created the variable `id`. Also, are you sure the post request requires JSON data and not HTTP form data?

Comment: I don't create variable id, I just pass it when user type something in textField and from my case I require json data  to post because there are another params that I need to pass in body (json form), but here I just show my incomplete body json

Comment: Change `onPressed: postId(id.text),` to `onPressed: () => postId(id.text),`. `onPressed` needs a `Function`.

Comment: it works fine with your solution, thank you very much :DD